# Xamarin: Method starts without ever beeing called for...?

Tags: xamarin

So, ive got these lines of code:

```
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof (Activity1).Name;
    Location _currentLocation;
    LocationManager _locationManager;

    string _locationProvider;
    TextView _locationText;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        _locationText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.GpsTest);

        InitializeLocationManager();

        Add700ToCoordinates();
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {

        _currentLocation = location;
        if (_currentLocation == null)
        {
            _locationText.Text = "Unable to determine your location. Try again in a short while.";
        }
        else
        {
            _locationText.Text = string.Format("{0:f6},{1:f6}", _currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude); 
            //das her wird ausgegeben bei button.click 
        }

    } // ausgabe der koordinaten 

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider) {}

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider) {}

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "{0}, {1}", provider, status);
    }

    void InitializeLocationManager()
    {
        _locationManager = (LocationManager) GetSystemService(LocationService);
        Criteria criteriaForLocationService = new Criteria
                                              {
                                                  Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine
                                              };
        IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = _locationManager.GetProviders(criteriaForLocationService, true);

        if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
        {
            _locationProvider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
        }
        else
        {
            _locationProvider = string.Empty;
        }
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Using " + _locationProvider + ".");
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_locationProvider, 0, 0, this);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Listening for location updates using " + _locationProvider + ".");
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        _locationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "No longer listening for location updates.");
    }

    public string StringWithLocation(Location location)
    {
        string StringWithCoordinates = "Null";

        _currentLocation = location;
        if (_currentLocation == null)
        {
            StringWithCoordinates = "Unable to determine your location. Try again in a short while.";
        }
        else
        {
            StringWithCoordinates = string.Format("{0:f6},{1:f6}", _currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);
        }

        return StringWithCoordinates;

    }

    public void Add700ToCoordinates()
    {
       // StringWithLocation(); 
    }

}
```

}

and there are four things i just cannot find out:

1) Where is my method "onLocationChanged(location location)" beeing called? I cant find it anywhere!!!

2) I edited the id-name of a button in my app and the app still works fine with the new button. I cant see where the button is initialized (I can find the TextView though). And i really don't know why it initialized itself... I should at least get an error...

3) usually, as I know, I need a button.click event, to get the result from a button. In this code there is no such thing, yet it works just fine... Does anyone know what causes this?

4) The method that gives me the result after I press my one button, that doesnt appear anywhere in the code..., is type void. So i cant return a string from it. Yet, when I make it string instead of void the IlocationListener gives an error, stating that the method needs to be void. How do i get that to work?

Thanks a lot for that! I wouldnt be able to progress with out you guys!

Comment: It is dll's method: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Locations.ILocationListener.OnLocationChanged/p/Android.Locations.Location/

Comment: so, if id like to call it myself, what would i need to fill into the parameters? it says (location location) at the end - what is stored in "location"?

Comment: It's happening because (presumably) your class is implementing ILocationListener.  If you look at the link FCin provided, you'll see that Location is hyperlinked to Android.Locations.Location

Comment: For 2) please show your UI code from the layout (.axml) file. For 3) that is odd. Does the button actually do anything? For 4) you can not change the signature of virtual methods that you are overriding. Also it makes no sense to return a string from a button event handler. Who is going to handle the returned string? The Android runtime? Because that is who called it. Android would not know what to  do with the string returned even if you could return a string.